# OpenGL error c1101

Tags: java, opengl, rendering, lwjgl

I'm following an online tutorial regarding building a game engine using LWJGL, I'm coming along great and really try to understand the code I'm being taught, however I now get this error and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I tried adding specular lighting, this is the tutorial I'm following if that helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZ_1xOm-3qU&index=12&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP

When I try to run my application this shows in my console:

```
Could not compile shader.
0(25) : error C1101: ambiguous overloaded function reference "mul(mat4, vec3)"
(0) : mat3x4 mul(mat3x1, mat1x4)
(0) : mat3 mul(mat3x1, mat1x3)
(0) : mat3x2 mul(mat3x1, mat1x2)
(0) : mat3x1 mul(mat3x1, mat1)
(0) : mat2x4 mul(mat2x1, mat1x4)
(0) : mat2x3 mul(mat2x1, mat1x3)
(0) : mat2 mul(mat2x1, mat1x2)
(0) : mat2x1 mul(mat2x1, mat1)
(0) : mat1x4 mul(mat1x3, mat3x4)
(0) : mat1x3 mul(mat1x3, mat3)
(0) : mat1x2 mul(mat1x3, mat3x2)
(0) : mat1 mul(mat1
```

This is the method that's outputting those messages:

```
if (GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
    System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 500));
    System.err.println("Could not compile shader.");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

I hope anyone could help fixing this, thanks in advance :)

With kind regards,
Stan

EDIT: Here's my shader code (indeed written in GLSL)

vertexShader.txt:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector;
out vec3 toCameraVector;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main(void) {

    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldPosition;
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;

    surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
    toLightVector = lightPosition - worldPosition.xyz;
    toCameraVector = inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;
}
```

fragmentShader.txt

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector;
in vec3 toCameraVector;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
uniform vec3 lightColour;
uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float reflectivity; 


void main(void) {

    vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
    vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);

    float nDotl = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
    float brightness = max(nDotl, 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = brightness * lightColour;

    vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);
    vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
    vec3 reflectedLightDirection = reflect(lightDirection, unitNormal);

    float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLightDirection, unitVectorToCamera);
    specularFactor = max(specularFactor, 0.0);
    float dampedFactor = pow(specularFactor, shineDamper);
    vec3 finalSpecular = dampedFactor * lightColour;

    out_Color = vec4(diffuse, 1.0) * texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords) + vec4(finalSpecular, 1.0);

}
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to compile a shader (probably written in [GLSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language)) and the shader compiler is telling you that there's something wrong with the code of the shader. What does the shader code look like?

Comment: @Jesper I added the shader codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert in GLSL but the error message seems to suggest that you are trying to multiply a `mat4` by a `vec3`, for which there is no multiply function available.

You are trying to do this in this line:

```
toCameraVector = inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;
```

Note that `inverse(viewMatrix)` is a `mat4` and `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0).xyz` is a `vec3`.

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, stupid how I just looked over it a billion times. Should've seen it myself, but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is: In line 25 of your shader you are trying to multiply a mat4 with a vec3 which is impossible.

```
toCameraVector = inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;
```

You can either multiply a mat4 by a vec4 or a mat3 by a vec3. When looking at the tutorial, you'll note that you removed some brackets:

```
toCameraVector = (inverse(viewMatrix) * vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)).xyz - worldPosition.xyz;
```

Note, that in the correct version you are multiplying a mat4 by a vec4 and afterwards clamp it to a vec3.